# Serviço java que consulte o SQLite uma vez ao dia

Tags: java, services

Sou novo em programação Android, gostaria de saber qual serviço java eu uso para consultar a base SQLite uma vez ao dia, quero que mesmo que desligue o aparelho ou reinicie, o serviço seja ativado novamente

Answer (score 1):

Caso sua aplicação esteja usando a tecnologia **EJB 3.1** (JavaEE) você poderá usar a anotação `@Schedule` no método para que este seja executado de acordo com a cronologia desejada, no seu caso poderia ser:

```
@Schedule(dayOfWeek="*", hour="0", minute="0")
```

Assim, sempre seria executada a ação de busca às 00:00 de cada dia.

Para saber mais como criar tarefas agendadas com EJB, recomendo [este link](http://blog.caelum.com.br/agendando-tarefas-com-o-timerservice-do-ejb-3-1/)

Comment: eu pretendo usar essa funcionalidade no Android porque estou desenvolvendo um aplicativo, você sabe me dizer se mesmo o com aplicativo fechado esse método executa o que eu quero ? vou precisar fazer uma consulta na base SQLite uma vez ao dia